# Does it still make sense to avoid creating objects for the sake of garbage collection?

Tags: java, java-8, garbage-collection, java-9

For example in a service adapter you might:

a. have an input data model and an output data model, maybe even immutable, with different classes and use Object Mappers to transform between classes and create some short-lived objects along the way

b. have a single data model, some of the classes might be mutable, but the same object that was created for the input is also sent as output

There are other use-cases when you'd have to choose between clear code with many objects and less clear code with less objects and I would like to know if Garbage Collection still has a weight in this decision.

Comment: Much has been achieved, short lived generation and even keeping short lived object fields on the stack. Go for the most solid logic, without unnecessary artefacts, and profile it (simple in NetBeans).

Comment: When you are talking about temporary objects only, well, then it doesn’t make much sense to try to avoid them, or, it makes sense only if the avoiding code still is as simple as the original one, i.e. if you’ve just have to make a choice between `int` and `Integer` or using `Comparator.comparingInt` instead of `Comparator.comparing`, sure, that still makes sense, as, even if it doesn’t improve performance (in a certain environment), it doesn’t harm. What you should *never* do, is trying to implement a cache for these objects or such alike…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should make this a comment as IMO it does not qualify as an answer, but it will not fit.

Even if the answer(s) are going to most probably be - do whatever makes your code more readable (and to be honest I still follow that all the time); we have faced this issue of `GC` in our code base.

Suppose that you want to create a graph of users (we had to - around 1/2 million) and load all their properties in memory and do some aggregations on them and filtering, etc. (it was not my decision), because these graph objects where pretty heavy - once loaded even with `16GB` of heap the `JVM` would fail with `OOM` or `GC` would take huge pauses. And it's understandable - lots of data requires lots of memory, you can't run away from it. The solution proposed and that actually worked was to model that with simple `BitSet`s - where each bit would be a property and a potential linkage to some other data; this is by far not readable and *extremely* complicated to maintain to this day. Lots of shifts, lots of intrinsics of the data - you have to know at all time what the 3-bit means for example, there's no `getter` for `usernameIncome` let's say - you have to do quite a lot shifts and map that to a search table, etc. But it would keep the `GC` pretty low, at least in the ranges where we were OK with that.

So unless you can prove that GC is taken your app time so much - you probably are even safer simply adding more RAM and increasing it(unless you have a leak). I would still go for `clear code` like `99.(99) %` of the time.

Comment: My tl;dr: choose clean code until you're sure that GC is an issue.

Comment: @Sorin absolutely!

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of Java have quite sophisticated mechanisms to handle very short-living objects so it's not as bad as it was in the past. With a modern JVM I'd say that you don't need to worry about garbage collection times if you create many objects, which is a good thing since there are now many more of them being created on the fly that this was the case with older versions of Java.

What's still valid is to keep the number of created objects low if the creation is coming with high costs, e.g. accessing a database to retrieve data from, network operations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As other people have said I think it's better to write your code to solve the problem in an optimum way for that problem rather than thinking about what the garbage collector (GC) will do.

The key to working with the GC is to look at the lifespan of your objects.  The heap is (typically) divided into two main regions called generations to signify how long objects have been alive (thus young and old generations).  To minimise the impact of GC you want your objects to become eligible for collection while they are still in the young generation (either in the Eden space or a survivor space, but preferably Eden space).  Collection of objects in the Eden space is effectively free, as the GC does nothing with them, it just ignores them and resets the allocation pointer(s) when a minor GC is finished.

Rather than explicitly calling the GC via `System.gc()` it's much better to tune your heap.  For example, you can set the size of the young generation using command line options like `-XX:NewRatio=n`, where n signifies the ratio of new to old (e.g. setting it to 3 will make the ratio of new:old 1:3 so the young generation will be 1 quarter of the heap). Alternatively, you can set the size explicitly using `-XX:NewSize=n` and `-XX:MaxNewSize=m`.  The GC may resize the heap during collections so setting these values to be the same will keep it at a fixed size.

You can profile your code to establish the rate of object creation and how long your objects typically live for.  This will give you the information to (ideally) configure your heap to minimise the number of objects being promoted into the old generation.  What you really don't want is objects being promoted and then becoming garbage shortly thereafter.

Alternatively, you may want to look at the Zing JVM from Azul (full disclosure, I work for them).  This uses a different GC algorithm, called C4, which enables compaction of the heap concurrently with application threads and so eliminates most of the impact of the GC on application latency.